# Using SYSTEM_USER as a parameter to a table valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, user-defined-functions

I've created a table valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TestFunction
(   
    @username VARCHAR(80)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT 0 AS TestValue
)
```

Then try to call it as so:

```
SELECT TestValue
FROM dbo.TestFunction(SYSTEM_USER)
```

but get the error:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SYSTEM_USER'

I've even tried making this a table valued function which is not inline, but I get the same error.

Am I missing something? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: This was asked yesterday (though the titles aren't obviously related). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318684/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-current-timestamp-but-only-on-one-database/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my 2k8 server I can only reproduce that with SQL Server 2000 (80) Compatibility level set, check the level of your 2005 database.

Meantime you can;

```
declare @su varchar(30) = SYSTEM_USER
select * from dbo.TestFunction(@su)
```

Comment: That's the problem. It's on an old database which is set to 2000 compatibility. Works fine on our other databases.

The problem with your solution, is that I can't use that in a view. I guess I could wrap that in a table valued function that is not inline.